# Combobox selected item from a different object

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I have a combobox and the list is populated using the AccountType class and the list is getting populated properly.

However when I bind the selected Item property to the Selected Account which is class account. On page load the selected item is not getting updated. All the other controls like textbox are getting updated.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

### View

```
ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccountTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountTypeName" 
  SelectedValuePath="AccountTypeName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}" />
```

### AccountType class

```
public class AccountType:IAccountType
{
    public string AccountTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

### Account Class

```
public class Account: IAccount
{
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string AccountTypeName { get; set; }
    public int SubAccount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

}
```

### Selected Account in ViewModel

```
    public IAccount SelectedAccount { get { return selectedAccount; }
        set { selectedAccount = value;  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `ViewModel` needs to be raising the `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Second, your binding should specify two-way binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccountTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountTypeName" 
  SelectedValuePath="AccountTypeName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

But third, and I think the main issue here, is that your Combo box is bound to a list of AccountTypes (i.e. `IAccountType`), yet you want the selected item to be an `IAccount`. But there is no property of type `IAccount` on an `IAccountType`.

So you need to bind the SelectedItem to an IAccountType property, or bind SelectedValue to a string property on your ViewModel. e.g.:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccountTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountTypeName"   
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccountType, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

and in your ViewModel have a property to bind to:

```
public IAccountType SelectedAccountType
{
    get { return selectedAccountType; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, selectedAccountType)) return;
        selectedAccountType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAccountType");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your prompt response, your views on how can I convert my IAccount SelectedAccount.AccountTypeName to IAccountType? or can you please post an example on how to convert my IAccount SelectedAccount.AccountTypeName to string? Is my Model implementation wrong? should I be using instead of  public string AccountTypeName { get; set; } in my IAccount Model something like public IAccountType AccountTypeName { get; set; } . Thanks

Comment: have you tried what I suggested? I'd go for a SelectedAccountType property of type IAccountType and then bind to it on SelectedItem

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark, As suggested I have created an IAccountType property and pulled the selected type using             SelectedType = AllAccountTypes.Where(x => x.AccountTypeName == SelectedAccount.AccountTypeName).FirstOrDefault();  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are binding SelectedItem to an IAccount object, but you are selecting a string from your dropdown list.

I would bind to a string instead, and then in the setter do what needs to be done to set the SelectedAccount property, something like this:

```
    public string SelectedAccountName
    {
        get { return _selectedAccountName; }
        set
        {
            _selectedAccountName = value;
            SelectedAccount = AllAccounts.Where(x => x.AccountName == _selectedAccountName).First();
        }
    }
```

With XAML like this (I added height and width values so the dropdown isn't massive):

```
<ComboBox Height="20" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccountTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountTypeName" SelectedValuePath="AccountTypeName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccountName}" />
```

Comment: Thanks JMK for your prompt response. I tried your code and somehow its not working.Just wanted to understand the lambda in the setter, Why are we updating the SelectedAccount?  x.AccountName == _selectedAccountName what does this mean? apologies for the inconvenience.. I am kind of new to lambda.. thanks.